Почему в приложении на flutter в yandex картах отображается только сетка?
Задача, сделать MVP приложение для android и ios, основной функционал завязан на Yandex карте. Но не могу запустить подложку карт на андроид (пробовал и эмулятор и физ. девайс)
Делал по гайду https://yandex.ru/dev/mapkit/doc/ru/flutter/generated/getting_started
В android разработке впервые, приложения из разряда hello world запускаются без проблем (:
Из файлов в проекте редактировал только lib>main.dart
Код:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yandex_maps_mapkit_lite/init.dart' as init;
import 'package:yandex_maps_mapkit_lite/mapkit.dart';
import 'package:yandex_maps_mapkit_lite/yandex_map.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
  await init.initMapkit(
    apiKey: 'a10c31db-4def-490c-93ff-***'
  );
            
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
  
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
  
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  MapWindow? _mapWindow;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: YandexMap(onMapCreated: (mapWindow) => _mapWindow = mapWindow)
      )
    );
  }
}

Результат (первый скриншот, сегодняшний, после установки VS C++, а вчера отображалась только сетка), пробовал запускать как на эмуляторе, так и на физ. устройстве Xiaomi Mi9


Что пишется в консоль(сегодня, левый скриншот):
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:63444/eVXZEU9Q80Y=/ws
9
E/emuglGLESv2_enc(17958): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2206 GL error 0x502
I/PlatformViewsController(17958): Hosting view in view hierarchy for platform view: 0
I/PlatformViewsController(17958): PlatformView is using SurfaceProducer backend
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(17958): Compat change id reported: 236825255; UID 10193; state: ENABLED
E/FrameEvents(17958): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
W/yandex.maps(17958): XMCuGl4Nfl5wkXbkDBlj: Create OpenGl ES context version 3
E/FrameEvents(17958): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/libEGL  (17958): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(17958): Compat change id reported: 193247900; UID 10193; state: ENABLED
E/FrameEvents(17958): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
2
E/emuglGLESv2_enc(17958): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2206 GL error 0x502
2
E/FrameEvents(17958): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону хоть копать? Спасибо всем огромное!
Уже не понимаю в чем дело, поиск решения в интернете результатов не дает, пробовал и другие гайды, но там появляются проблемы из разряда flutter перешел на более новую версию и структура где то поменялась.
Ссылка на весь проект: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/rFAsJmEhWCHZrg
P.S. Важно что бы в приложении были именно Yandex карты.

Пожалуйста, прикрепите к вопросу или пришлите в поддержку на maps-api@support.yandex.ru полный пример собранного кода для проверки. Вы можете выложить его проектом на GitHub, прикрепить к переписке в архиве или загрузить на Яндекс Диск и указать ссылку.

Может быть такое, что карта не работает на эмуляторе. Возможно ей нужна геолокация и прочие штуки именно настоящего сотового.
